# How Do I Compile Apache httpd 2.4.16 with systemd Support?

Tags: apache, systemd

To assure that I am have complete control over my Apache httpd configuration for production purposes, I'm building httpd from source, on CentOS 7.

Configuration, make, and install work fine.  I'm using:

```
./configure --with-mpm=prefork --with-mysql --prefix=/usr/local/apache2 --enable-so --enable-ssl --enable-rewrite
```

The built web server works fine using apachectl, but CentOS 7 uses systemd instead of upstart, so utilizing systemctl requires that I have an `httpd.service` built and installed into `/lib/systemd/system`

How do I build that?

Answer (score 4):

This is what I did, I created the file /etc/systemd/system/apache.service
(This assumes your apachectl is located in /usr/apache/bin) as follows:

```
[Unit]
Description=The Apache HTTP Server

[Service]
Type=forking
EnvironmentFile=/usr/apache/bin/envvars
PIDFile=/var/apache/httpd.pid
ExecStart=/usr/apache/bin/apachectl start
ExecReload=/usr/apache/bin/apachectl graceful
ExecStop=/usr/apache/bin/apachectl stop
KillSignal=SIGCONT
PrivateTmp=true


[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

Then run systemctl  enable apache

Comment: Thanks for posting this. Did you also create the PIDFile at `/var/apache/httpd.pid` or is this auto-generated?

Comment: That would be created by apache using the PidFile directive.